# Detect real start of HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, cancellation, servicepoint, servicepointmanager

I'm a web crawler written using the [TAP pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) API of `HttpWebRequest`.

I want to download some stuff from `http://somedomain.tld` but I might end up sending quite a number of requests. I don't know if `somedomain.tld` will  respond in a timely fashion and I'd like to give it no more than 10s per request to complete sending back a response. I also want to take advantage of the connection limits enforced by the `ServicePoint` for that domain.

So I need to be able to time out on a request. Normally, I'd get a cancellation token from a `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10d))
```

and supply that to my async operations, and perhaps also register a cancellation callback that calls `myWebRequest.Abort()`, so I end up with a (simplified) method that looks something like this:

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetResponseData(Uri uri, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    ct.Register(wr.Abort);
    using(var response = await wr.GetResponseAsync())
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using(var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        await responseStream.CopyToAsync(ms,4096,ct);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

}
```

So far, so good.

Let me constrain things a little:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://somedomain.tld");
var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri);
sp.ConnectionLimit = 1;
```

Now, the `ServicePoint` instance associated with `somedomain.tld` will only allow a single request at a time.

Now I fire off two requests simultaneously, safe in the knowledge that the `ServicePoint` will insulate the target domain from my abuses:

```
var dataTasks = Enumerable.Range(0,2).Select(async _=>{
    using(var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10d)))
    {
        return await GetResponseData(uri,cts.Token);
    }
});

var datas = await Task.WhenAll(dataTasks);
```

Now, let's assume that the first request takes over 10s to complete... because I have constrained the `ServicePoint` to only fire off a single request at a time, by the time the `ServicePoint` gets round to firing off the second request, it's already been cancelled and aborted.

So how do I know when the request is ***actually*** being sent? How do I set a timeout that is "aware" of the actions of the `ServicePoint` with regards to a specific request?